# i want to create a module on drupal 9

Tags: forms, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-9

I'm a junior developper and I want to create a module on drupal 9, but I don't know where to start... I was thinking about create a module that says "hello world" just to understand how it works.
Can I have some help ? :)

Thanks,
Mélissandre

I've already installed a module on drupal 7 : yakforms. I saw that it was not migrated to drupal 9 because it is based on another module : formbuilder that is not migrated either, so I want to do it by myself. But first of all I need to understand how to create a module !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try resources such as:

https://www.drupal.org/docs/creating-modules

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mHTuXXfBs7Y

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OBuOFAca4kM

Or try using drush to generate code, someting like:

```
drush generate module
```